# How to show DAX Cumulative Sum of Current Year and Previous Year on same visual?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to show the running totals (Rolling 12 months, not a calendar YTD) (cumulative sum) of revenue on the same graph (sharing the same date axis).
I created a measure for the current year cumulative sum that works fine:

```
$CumulativeBookingRevenueCY = 
CALCULATE(
    [$Revenue],
    FILTER(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'DimDateBooking',
                'DimDateBooking'[Date]
            ),
            ALL('DimDateBooking')
        ),
        ISONORAFTER(
            'DimDateBooking'[Date], MAX(DimDateBooking[Date]), DESC
        )
    )
)
```

But I can't figure out what is wrong with the previous year measure. This is the code I am using:

```
$CumulativeBookingRevenueLY = 
CALCULATE(
    [$Revenue LY],
    FILTER(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'DimDateBooking',
                'DimDateBooking'[Date]
            ),
            SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('DimDateBooking'[Date])
        ),
        ISONORAFTER(
            SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('DimDateBooking'[Date]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(LASTDATE(DimDateBooking[Date])), DESC
        )
    )
)
```

Where my revenue measures are defined as follows:

```
$Revenue:= CALCULATE(Sum(FactTable[Revenue]))
$Revenue LY:= CALCULATE([$Revenue], DATEADD(DimDate[Date],-1,YEAR))
```

This is a sample of my data (CY is working, LY is not)

[image: Measure problem]

Can someone tell me what am I missing or doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a a few more steps.

You have:

`$Revenue:= CALCULATE(Sum(FactTable[Revenue]))`

`$Revenue LY:= CALCULATE([$Revenue], DATEADD(DimDate[Date],-1,YEAR))`

Use these additional measures below that incorporate the above measures, in your table:

`revenue_last_year = IF( LASTDATE(Dates[Date]) > TODAY(), BLANK(), CALCULATE([$Revenue LY], DATESYTD(Dates[Date])))`

`revenue_this_year = IF( LASTDATE(Dates[Date]) > TODAY(), BLANK(), CALCULATE([$Revenue], DATESYTD(Dates[Date])))`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Almost! The only thing about your measures is that I would like to have a rolling 12 months and not a calendar YTD. So close, thank you for your input